# SQL query to get what percentage of product categories have never been sold

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the below 4 tables with relationship

```
# sales                                # products
        +------------------+---------+         +---------------------+---------+
        | product_id       | INTEGER |>--------| product_id          | INTEGER |
        | store_id         | INTEGER |    +---<| product_class_id    | INTEGER |
        | customer_id      | INTEGER |    |    | brand_name          | VARCHAR |
   +---<| promotion_id     | INTEGER |    |    | product_name        | VARCHAR |
   |    | store_sales      | DECIMAL |    |    | is_low_fat_flg      | TINYINT |
   |    | store_cost       | DECIMAL |    |    | is_recyclable_flg   | TINYINT |
   |    | units_sold       | DECIMAL |    |    | gross_weight        | DECIMAL |
   |    | transaction_date | DATE    |    |    | net_weight          | DECIMAL |
   |    +------------------+---------+    |    +---------------------+---------+
   |                                      |
   |    # promotions                      |    # product_classes
   |    +------------------+---------+    |    +---------------------+---------+
   +----| promotion_id     | INTEGER |    +----| product_class_id    | INTEGER |
        | promotion_name   | VARCHAR |         | product_subcategory | VARCHAR |
        | media_type       | VARCHAR |         | product_category    | VARCHAR |
        | cost             | DECIMAL |         | product_department  | VARCHAR |
        | start_date       | DATE    |         | product_family      | VARCHAR |
        | end_date         | DATE    |         +---------------------+---------+
        +------------------+---------+
```

I want to get what percentage of product categories have never been sold.

I have tried this :

```
select 100.0* sum(case when spid is null OR 0 then 1.0 end)/count(ppid) as pct from 
(
Select distinct product_category, s.product_id as spid, p.product_id as ppid from products p 
LEFT JOIN Sales s on s.product_id = p.product_id
  LEFT JOIN product_classes pc ON pc.product_class_id = p.product_class_id
 LEFT JOIN Promotions pr on pr.promotion_id=s.promotion_id
)t
```

which gives 20.7

Expected answer is 13.8888

Comment: If you want to calculate the percentage of product classes that have never been sold, then you should divide the number of product_class_ids that do not have any sales with the number of all product_class_ids.

Comment: @Shadow : I tried this logic its not giving expected output `Select cast(count(distinct product_class_id)/(select count(distinct product_class_id) from product_classes) as float ) as x from

(
select p.product_class_id from products p 
 JOIN Sales s on s.product_id = p.product_id
 JOIN product_classes pc ON pc.product_class_id = p.product_class_id 
)t` to get % of product_groups that did sell

Comment: We cannot see your data, so it is a bit vague what you want. You need to define the algorithm for the calculaion and implement it. We cannot come up with the algorithm itself. I noticed that the product classes table have both product category and product subcategory fields. Perhaps you have multiple product_class_ids per product category (this means we the table is not properly normalised)

Answer (score 1):

```
select 100 - (select count(distinct product_category) * 1.0 as sold_product_category
    from product_classes
    join products
      on product_classes.product_class_id = products.product_class_id
    join sales
      on products.product_id = sales.product_id) * 100 / count(distinct product_category) * 1.0 as pct_product_categories_never_sold
     from product_classes
```

1. joining tables together filters the tables even further
2. by joining product_classes with products with sales you get the product categories that have been sold
3. problem is that product_classes lists product so there are multiple product categories, you have to filter those out with distinct
4. `100 - (sold product categories / total product categories)` gives us the product categories that haven't been sold

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get it by dividing the number of product classes by the number of classes which don't have any sales.

You don't need to join `promotions` table at all.

```
SELECT (
           SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM product_classes c
           WHERE EXISTS(
                         SELECT 1
                         FROM products p,
                              sales s
                         WHERE p.product_id = s.product_id
                           AND p.product_class_id = c.product_class_id
                         LIMIT 1
                     )
       ) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM product_classes c) * 100;
```

Comment: It doesn't return expected percentage